# How to use android pay to gain info for an app

Tags: android, android-pay, android-developer-api

For an app i am working on I need to get info whenever someone pays for something and what the amount is(its a budget app so I need to know the info to help with keeping a budget). Is there a way to access this and only this, I don't want any info besides this.

To reiterate is there an API for android that tells me when someone purchases something and how much it was

Thank You

Comment: is that payment is given through your app or you want information about payments done in the whole device ?.

Comment: The payment would be in the whole device. Preferably i would also get stuff like credit card purchases, but the main goal is to have people be able to check if they are spending within a budget and for that i would like to use android pay.

Comment: i think there is no option at this time of point

Comment: alright thank you for your time